# How to ensure a valid date in PHP?

Tags: php, validation, date

I have been using the date_parse method for input validation, which seems to be just fine... except it's not actually validating the date for correctness.

For example:

```
date_parse("2010/9/31/"); // returns FALSE 
date_parse("2010-9-31"); // should return FALSE!
```

How can I get it to validate that 2010-9-31 is, in fact, an invalid date?

Comment: Actually, neither date is valid, because september simply doesn't have 31 days.

Comment: @genesis: Have a look at a calendar: They aren't valid...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php 
function is_date( $str ) 
{ 
  $stamp = strtotime( $str ); 

  if (!is_numeric($stamp)) 
  { 
     return FALSE; 
  } 
  $month = date( 'm', $stamp ); 
  $day   = date( 'd', $stamp ); 
  $year  = date( 'Y', $stamp ); 

  if (checkdate($month, $day, $year)) 
  { 
     return TRUE; 
  } 

  return FALSE; 
} 
?>
```

source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php

Comment: This function will return incorrect results. For example it will return `TRUE` when `$str = '2012-02-31';`. The problem lies with `strtotime()` it will attempt to translate the date to `02/03/2012` which `checkdate()` sees as valid.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, `2010-9-31` is a valid date, so the return you're getting is correct behavior.

If you're trying to force a specific format, you may want to use [date_parse_from_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php)

```
print_r(date_parse_from_format("Y.n.j", $date));
```

Or, if that isn't sufficient, use [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) on $date before parsing it. If you do decide to use preg_match, you may want to ask a second question.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean what I think you mean, then you should take a look at [`checkdate`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php).

```
var_dump(checkdate(12, 31, 2000)); // true
var_dump(checkdate(2, 29, 2001)); // false, because was not a leap year
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$d = date_parse("2010-9-31");
if(count($d["warnings"]) > 0) { 
  echo array_shift($d["warnings"]) . "\n"; 
}

// --> "The parsed date was invalid"
```